# javascript update view if value change

Tags: javascript, websocket

i have java script where im getting value from websocets server, is updating the view every 1 sec , i will like to have the view only to be updated when the value change (add new point on the chart ),  as for now is updating every time even if the value is the same,

```
    <script>
var chartT = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart:{ renderTo : 'chart-temperature' },
  title: { text: 'Module Voltage' },
  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: []
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    line: { animation: false,
      dataLabels: { enabled: true }
    },
    series: { color: '#059e8a' }
  },
  xAxis: { type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { second: '%H:%M:%S' }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: { text: 'Voltage (V)' }
    //title: { text: 'Temperature (Fahrenheit)' }
  },
  credits: { enabled: false }
});
setInterval(function ( ) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
          y = parseFloat(this.responseText);
      //console.log(this.responseText);
      if(chartT.series[0].data.length > 40) {
        chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true, true);
      } else {
        chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, false, true);
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/temperature", true);
  xhttp.send();
}, 1000 ) ;


</script>
```

Comment: I don't see a websocket connected in your code.

Comment: this is arduino project if that will help

Comment: and maybe this will help more , i will like to add new point on the chart if the value change only

Comment: added a answer. I understood your question only I had doubt that you have written web socket but I was unable to discover any web socket connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping only the interval code here.

So if you are using websocket library such as socket.io then you can update the view when the socket emit event irrespective of the previous and current value.

While you are using the plain api call here and you wish to update the value only when data changes and you have called `setInterval` that will call after every 1 second. Than it will be good to store the value in json object and validate the changes.

Such as below I have initialized a json object name `change` as `{}`. So the view will be updated or position will be rendered only when there are change in x and y.

```
<script>
const change = {};
setInterval(function ( ) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
          y = parseFloat(this.responseText);
      if (!change[`${y}`]) {
           if(chartT.series[0].data.length > 40) {
             chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true, true);
         } else {
            chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, false, true);
        }
        change[`${y}`] = true;
      }
     
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/temperature", true);
  xhttp.send();
}, 1000 ) ;


</script>
```

Comment: thx for the answer , but unfortunately is still adding new point on the chart even if value is the same (and i dont need to use interval if the is another option )

Comment: See I understood the reason... you are fetching the time in `x` and with value you mean `y`. Because `x` will keep changing. So instead of `change[`${x}-${y}`]` use `change[`${y}`]`

Comment: unfortunately still the same :(

Comment: all work good , `change[${y}]` was the right shot. sorry forgot to refresh page , Thank you